# java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter

Tags: java, certificate, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am using EWSJavaAPI 1.1.5 to connect to Exchange Server 2010.

Everything was working fine until today while trying to connect to the server, I am getting the following exception:

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Fri Dec 28 01:26:27 GMT+02:00 2012
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.bindToFolder(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService.bindToFolder(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Folder.bind(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Folder.bind(Unknown Source)
    at com.xeno.phonesuite.web.Mail.Mail.authenticate(Mail.java:100)
    at org.apache.jsp.mailandcalendar.dologin_jsp._jspService(dologin_jsp.java:121)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Fri Dec 28 01:26:27 GMT+02:00 2012
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1649)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1206)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:893)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:632)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:506)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.HttpClientWebRequest.executeRequest(Unknown Source)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ServiceRequestBase.emit(Unknown Source)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Fri Dec 28 01:26:27 GMT+02:00 2012
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(CertificateValidity.java:256)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:570)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:543)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.EwsX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1198)
    ... 49 more
```

Please advise why I am getting this exception and how to solve it, thanks.

Comment: The server certificate has expired on December 28 2012, so verification fails.

Comment: @guido, can i edit the certificate or ignore this verification, since i am using the server for testing

Comment: If you generated the certificate yourself, you can just generate another one and install on the server. Or, you can try to bypass verification. I did that for hostname verification a couple of times, or for non-trusted certificates, i dont know if a NotValidAfter can be bypassed. This helped me, see if it can help you as well: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/how-to-bypass-certificate-checking-in-a-java-web-service-client/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Exchange server certificate was expired so i removed it and created a new one.

Comment: Can you please provide info/link on removal of expired certificate and creation of new one. I am facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to reinstall java that worked for me.

I recomend https://sdkman.io/ app to install java or maven.